# Call generic method with name from variable in angular 14

Tags: angular, function, generics, dynamic, call

I am using a dynamic function call where I take the name of the function to call from a string variable. This looks like this:

```
this.apiService[stringVariableWithFunctionName](queryParams).subscribe(...)
```

apiService has plenty functions calling an API and providing an observable.

This was always working fine with Angular 13.3.9. Now I started a new project with Angular 14.2.7 and this seems no longer being possible since I get following error-Message now:

"Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ApiService'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ApiService'.ts(7053)"

Both projects do have the same TS version 4.6.4.

I am pretty desperate since I searched for days now but did not find any working solution. Thank you for any help!

Regards

I was trying to call a dynamic function with the name from a string variable

API Service excerpt: createIncident is an example method for dynamic call.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, take} from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient
  ) { }

  createincident(inc:any){
    var req = environment.ApiBaseURL + 'createIncident';
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    var body:any = {};
    body['values'] = inc;
    headers = headers.append('authorization', token);
    return this.httpClient.post(req, body, { headers });
  }
...
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of ApiService?

Comment: @Ardit  added the example to the question.